# Javac через командную строку

Tags: java, консоль, javac

Проблема с пакетами.
В главной папке : http://image.prntscr.com/image/4d767d9e4f44452eb962984d59ec7fa2.png

**Код файла "1" :**

```
import mainpackage.*;
class MainClass {
public static void main (String[] s){
SeparationClass o = new SeparationClass();
for(int i=1; i<=8; ++i){
for(int j=1; j<=8; ++j){
o.setA(i);
o.setB(j);
System.out.print(o.deduct() + " ");
}
System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

в папке main http://image.prntscr.com/image/19c8976c0525489ab65dcbefca4e8847.png

**Код файла "2" :**

```
package myfirstpackage;
class SeparationClass {
private int a;
private int b;
SeparationClass () {a = 0;b = 0;}
public void setA(int a) {this.a = a;}
public void setB(int b) {this.b = b;}
public int deduct() {return a - b;}
}
```

При компиляции выдает ошибку: 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/66c07183f0b14704bfabc65529861b82.png

Объясните пожалуйста где ошибка.

Comment: фото можно прям сюда загружать. не стесняться.. а ошибку как цитату оформлять

Comment: Попробуйте переименовать пакет файла 2 c myfirstpackage -> mainpackage

Comment: Это не помогло. Ошибка в компиляции 1.java

Comment: Решил проблему.